# Is my game exploitable?

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

It is a game with the following rules. It is loosely based off a game called [goofspiel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goofspiel) but I want to see if the rules can apply to a continuous variant.

- There are 2 players $A$ and $B$.
- Each defines a "play function" $\mathcal{P}$. $A$ defines $\mathcal{P}_A$  and B defines $\mathcal{P}_B$.
- A play function $\mathcal{P}$ must satisfy some constraints:

  1. The [domain and codomain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function#Formal_definition) of $\mathcal{P}$ are $(0,1)$.
  2. $\int_0^1 \mathcal{P}(x)\;dx=0.5$
  3. $\int_0^1 \ln(\mathcal{P}(x)/x)\;dx=0$
- Given the "contest function" $\mathcal{C}$ as
  $$\mathcal{C}(x)=\begin{cases}
  \;1 & \text{if}\quad\mathcal{P}_A > \mathcal{P}_B \\
  \;0 & \text{if}\quad\mathcal{P}_A = \mathcal{P}_B \\
  -1 & \text{if}\quad\mathcal{P}_A < \mathcal{P}_B \\
  \end{cases}$$
  Player $A$ wins if $\int_0^1 x\;\mathcal{C}(x)\;dx > 0$, otherwise $B$ wins. (We can suppose a tie if it works out to exactly $0$, if that makes a difference.)

The game is zero sum and symmetric. In Goofspiel, there is no pure Nash equilibrium.
**Does my variant of this game also have no pure Nash equilibrium or is there an exploit that I didn't account for?**

Comment: Is there any significance to $0.5$ in rule 2? Similarly, the significance of rule 3 isn't clear to me.

Comment: Suppose we define a $\mathcal{P_{A'}}$ by $\mathcal{P_{A'}} = 2\mathcal{P_B}-\mathcal{P_A}$. Then player $A$ wins the $\mathcal{\langle A',B\rangle}$ game iff player $B$ wins the $\mathcal{\langle A,B\rangle}$ game. Is this enough to give you your result?

Comment: a(p) = p is a function that fits this criteria. The area under the curve is 1/2. I chose 1/2 because it made the problem simpler.

Comment: This is my reasoning for rule 3. I want every value of a(p1) to not be equal to a(p2) for all p1 and p2 in P. But this rule is insufficient for a continuous variant. It would be easy to exploit with any continuous function. In goofspiel, the sum of the inputs and the product of the inputs from the players are identical. The only change is the ordering. Is rule 3 sufficient to capture this idea in a continuous game?

Comment: Players A and B play P_a and P_b simultaneously. So I don't think that would do it.

Comment: Another function that I think works is a piecewise function. f(x)={x+.1 if x<=.9, x-.9 if x>.9}